# How to programatically set Android application theme for all activities

Tags: android

I have already googled setting application themes quite a bit and what I found was to either use the `AndroidManifest.xml` or to set it use `setTheme` before `setContentView` is called. I am going to allow users to switch between 2 themes I have created  in the settings so I have to go the `setTheme` route. I have already figured out how to set it but I am wondering how I would set the user selected theme to ALL activities. Currently it only applies to the main activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO the best approach is creating a `BaseActivity` extending `Activity` to do the `setTheme()` in `onCreate()` based on the settings.
Then let every Activity extend `BaseActivity`.

Comment: So currently my main activity is called MainActivity (lol)... would i set the BaseActivity as the new main or just create the BaseActivity and have the Main extend the base?

Comment: depending on your plan of adding more activities. If you plan to have a lot of them, it's easier to extend `BaseActivity`. Inlining the code is still an option though.

Comment: No you misunderstood my question, although it was my fault for explain so poorly. What I meant was, the activity that is called when the app first loads is MainActivity. Would I have to change that to BaseActivity?

Comment: No, you don't, just extend it from `BaseActivity`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a abstract activity that will be your base activity, and have all your activities extend from that activity.

Your base activity can then contain the logic for setting the theme. i.e in the onCreate check which theme it should be using, and then set it.

If all of your activities call the onCreate super before setting the content view, then the theming will be taken care of.